# How to get only currentUser related content in NestJs with prisma

Tags: nestjs, prisma

Im creating a multi company app which logged user will only have access to his content. At the moment i don't want to implement multi tentant in this app.

I have created a Decorator to get the current logged user:

```
import { createParamDecorator, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
  (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
    const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return request.user;
  },
);
```

And used this decorator on my controller actions to get the companyId of the user and pass this ID to the service.

```
 @Get()
  async getAll(
    @CurrentUser()
    currentUser,
  ) {
    return this.categoryService.getAll(currentUser.companyId);
  }
```

Now, on service i have access to the companyId and can access his content:

```
  async getAll(companyId: string) {
    const categories = await this.prisma.category.findMany({
      where: { companyId: companyId },
    });

    return categories;
  }
```

The BIG problem is that i will have to repeat this process in every controller, services and etc.

Is there any easier way to do this? Anything i can use on the service level? How can i solve this?

Comment: What would the optimal solution look like to you? 

If all requests include `where { companyId }` is what you are checking always, that can be done at a prisma level, but if you want it for just one service at a time, you can always Inject(REQUEST) into the service.

Comment: I have tryied to inject the request into the service, like this:

```
@Inject(REQUEST) private readonly request: Request
```

but when i try to access the companyId of the user with (this.request.user.companyId) , im receiving this error: property user does not exist on type User

Comment: why don't use middleware??

Comment: Idea is very good, im using similar approach, but 1st - type the currentUser in controller, also that user might not be there - i mean, i dont know what you are using for log in (i think jwt - passport) if so - you also need to ensure that is also executed to have the user on your route.  Then you can have as many parameters in yours `currentUser` as you want, and use it for access parameters

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to achieve exactly, but I will do this:

```
/* File: CategoryService.ts */

import { Injectable, Scope, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from 'express';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class CategoryService {
  // declare your variables/properties

  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request) {

  }

  // get current user
  getCurrentUserCompanyId() {
    return this.request.user['companyId'];
  }

  async getAll() {
    const categories = await this.prisma.category.findMany({
      where: { companyId: this.getCurrentUserCompanyId() },
    });

    return categories;
  }
}


/* File: category.controller.ts */
@Controller('category')
export class CategoryController {

  constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService) {}

  @Get()
  async getAll() {
    return this.categoryService.getAll();
  }
}
```

Comment: Good aproach but don't work as expected. I this case, i need to access the companyId property on the this.request.user. But if i try to access the companyId, it says that the property companyId dont exist on type user.  like this : return this.request.user.companyId

Comment: are you sure that you send `companyId` along with the request? This is scoped-request bubble up from the controller. Add a `console.log(this.request.user)` to confirm your request data.

Comment: Yes. If i console.log(this.request.user) is returning the User object with all of his properties.
Now i can solve the problem with this:  this.request.user['companyId'];  But i dont understand why using this.request.user.companyId dont works. :-(

Comment: as far as I can see, because we access the `request.user` directly from the type in the constructor `private request: Request`, it is not transformed into class object.

Answer (score 0):

Hello, one of the simplest ways to do this is `userGuard`, you need `jwt token` to use it. Now you may be wondering what useguards are and how they are used.I want to give to you real example,

```
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";
import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
import { Strategy,ExtractJwt } from "passport-jwt";


@Injectable()
export class  JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy,'jwt') {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      secretOrKey: 'super-secret-cat',
    });
  }
  async validate(payload: any) {
    
 
    return payload
  }
}
```

This is a simple JWT guard.First checks for jwt login, then using

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard("jwt")
```

You verify your authenticates the user
For more information
https://docs.nestjs.com/guards